# Can I take text which is in a csv and make it the name of the csv file

Tags: command-line, gedit, csv

I really hope I can explain my issue. Your help will be much appreciated.

I have over 1000 csv files which looks exactly the same.
Example

```
Malian Aero Company,,,,,Aircraft,TZ-DDG,(Seed 1),,,Block-on (Z),18:19,      Landing (Z),,18:14,Date,06/06/16
2016  MALI  WEATHER  MODIFICATION  PROGRAM,,,,,,,,,,Block-off (Z),16:35,        Takeoff (Z),,16:41,Page,1
,Pilot:,Daniel Chacon,,Co-Pilot:,Malik,,Observer: ,,,Total Time,01:44,    Flight  Time    ,,01:33,Type,Seed
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Time,Cell,Event,LAT,LON,Alt.,Ejectable (Glacio),,BIP (Hygro),,Remarks,,,,,,
(UTC),No.,No.,(VOR),(DME),(Kft),0,Recycle,Burn,Recycle,,,,,,,
17:03,1,,12.55,-9.03,"8,000",,,1,,,,,,,,
17:06,,,12.67,-9.13,"8,000",,,1,,Updraft 500/900 ft/m,,,,,,
17:11,,,12.56,-9.11,"8,000",,,1,,,,,,,,
17:13,,,12.74,-9.07,"8,000",,,1,,,,,,,,
17:35,2,,13.31,-9.07,"9,000",,,1,,,,,,,,
17:39,,,13.53,-9.05,"9,000",,,1,,,,,,,,
```

The problem is I want the name of the csv file to be the date that the flight took place which is in line 2. In this example, the date is `06/06/16`. Therefore, I want the name of the csv file to be `20160606`. Note the change in order which probably makes it a bit more confusing.

How can I do this automatically?

Comment: Hi @suraj, the edit was incorrect, this is no code, the landing date ended on the wrong line :)

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) and [edit] your question making sure the example data is correct. Ideally, format the example data as code (`{}`) so it uses a fixed-width font and we can understand better. Is that supposed to be one long line or many? What is the format of the file? Will the data always be a specific field? Which field? Are fields defined by commas?

Comment: @JacobVlijm oops sorry I approved suraj's edit - and now I think I've screwed up your rollback as well. I will go drink some coffee now.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I see. apologies.. Block quotes for  csv data then

Comment: @suraj no problem, I could have done the same, until I read the question :)

Comment: OK, I *think* my last edit is correct and represents your actual data. Please let me know if it isn't. Also don't ask multiple questions in a single post and make sure to explain how we can know how to find the date.

Comment: @terdon You can find the date by parsing the last comma delimited field of the first line of the cvs file.

Comment: @L.D.James only if all files have the date as the last field of the first line. That's what I had wanted the OP to clarify. Is it always the last field? Or is it the 17th field? Or something else?

Comment: I was referring to the part of his message, the second line which specified the format of all the files are exact, if which he showed one of the files.  When answering questions, I often miss details like that in a question.  When reading your command, I happened to notice that it appeared to have already been addressed in the question.  Of course, I understand what appears very apparent to me, might not necessarily appear the same way to the next person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script has two arguments.  One for the directory for your csv files.  The other for the new files corrected.

In case you have more than one flight on the same day, I added the time as part of the filename to ensure there is a unique name for each outfile.

**The script:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

indir=$HOME/indir
outdir=$HOME/outdir

[[ -d $outdir ]] || (echo "Outdir doesn't exist... Exiting..." ; exit) 

process() {
    file=$1
    datetime=$(head -1 $file|awk -F, '{print $NF"/"$(NF-2)}' | sed s#/#:#g)

    IFS=':' read -r -a arr <<< "$datetime"
    newname=$(printf "20${arr[2]}${arr[0]}${arr[1]}-${arr[3]}${arr[4]}.csv\n")
    echo "Name Change: $file -> $newname"
    sed -e '1,7d' < $file > $outdir/$newname
}

for i in "$indir"/*.csv; do
    process "$i"
done
```

**Script Summary**

**Variables and commands of the script:**

- indir: The script using the variables **indir** for the directory of your csv files.
- oudir: Create this directory for the new files to be copied.
- First line: Verifies the out directory exist before continuing the script.
- arr: An array variable for splitting the date and creating the new filename.
- sed: A commandline text editor used for deleting the unwanted lines.

Comment: An explanation of the script would be nice.

Comment: @Melebius I tried to use self-explanatory variables.  Originally the array variable was named **array**, I shortened to `arr` to avoid horizontal scroll for viewing the whole script.  The first line verifies the output directory before continuing.  The Second section creates the new name out of the date.  The **sed** command deletes the first 7 lines (lines - through 7).

Comment: I personally can read your script but OP probably not. Since they did not mention any tried commands, for example, I guess they could not read your code with pipelines, a command substitution, `sed`, `awk` and so on. And last but not least, the explanation should be a part of the answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably going to make Baby Jesus (or at least, Larry Wall) cry, but:

```
prename -n '
  use Text::CSV;
  use Time::Piece;
  open my $fh, "<", $_ or die "$_ : $!";
  eval {
    my $r = Text::CSV->new()->getline($fh);
    s{.*(?=\.csv)}{Time::Piece->strptime($r->[-1], "%d/%m/%y")->strftime("%Y%m%d")}e  if ($r);
    1;
  } 
  or do {
    print "$_ skipped (no valid date field found)\n"
  }
' *.csv
file1.csv renamed as 20160606.csv
file2.csv renamed as 20160623.csv
file3.csv skipped (no valid date field found)
file.csv : Permission denied at (eval 8) line 4.
```

NOTE:

1. it assumes that the date is in the last column of the first line of each file
2. it assumes the original date format is `"%d/%m/%y"` but the example you've given could be read as `"%m/%d/%y"` - you will need to check and adjust if necessary

It should skip files from which it is unable to parse a valid date in the expected location: the error handling for the date parsing is taken from [Exception handling in Perl: How to deal with fatal errors in external modules](https://perlmaven.com/fatal-errors-in-external-modules).

*Remove the* `-n` *only if/when you are convinced it is doing the right thing.*

Answer (score -4):

You could use `cut` to select the exact column you need, then you could use `date` ([for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842634/parse-date-in-bash), in combination with sed) to set the filename.

Put this in a loop to go through all your files and you're done.

To help you on the way:

```
cut --delim="," -f17 yourfile.csv | head -n1
```

This will select the date, now it's your turn to transform it.

Comment: Put what in a loop? You aren't actually providing any command here.

Comment: @terdon See edit, but also note I am here to provide an answer, not to code the whole thing up. I don't do other people's homework :)

Comment: In that case, please don't post "answers" that don't even attempt to actually provide an answer and only give a first approximation for only one of the many steps needed. And how do you know that the date is always the 17th field of the first line? How will the OP take this to rename their file? Come on. Either answer the question or don't.

Comment: Disagreed, so I'll take that downvote with pride. The OP might not know  of the command line tools that are available and am pointing him/her towards them: cut, date, and a for loop. Work done.

Comment: Also, @terdon if the date is not always in the same column, then that is a completely different question. This *is* an answer.

Comment: Not column, *line*. The OP states that "the date [. . .] which is in line 2". Which is not very clear and quite confusing, but there it is.

Comment: @terdon, he referred to line 2 in his original post which you edited. If the assumption is wrong that the data is structured, you should close the question.

Comment: True. I'm hoping the OP will confirm. My was based on the source of what the OP [had posted](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/b7f67c2f-bd6a-4be1-896b-3f8513263b05/view-source) (where the date was on the first line) and I am assuming (possible incorrectly) that the OP only mentioned the second line because of how the data appeared after posting.